# how to detect unbalanced special characters in string

Tags: grep, string, pattern-matching, ack

I'm wondering what would be the best way (likely using **grep** or **ack**) to return lines containing *unbalanced special character sets* in a string? For example, if the string were:

```
bqM#+t1U"OyBGhk]ozVG[v"&
```

and the specified character were a double-quote ("), this line would not be returned. However, what I'm looking for is more complicated, requiring a left and right balance, for instance a left square parenthesis ([) and a right square parenthesis (]). Then the line would be returned if the number of ([) does not equal the number of (]) such as:

```
i],U2y.2<i*gZCl>y[A~a`^[
```

Comment: "but this one would", this one would what? Fail or succeed? Is it considered balanced or unbalanced and why?

Comment: @JamesRisner : Sorry, I misspoke. Correction made. That line is considered "unbalanced" because it has two left square brackets and only one right square bracket.

Comment: Is ack supposed to be awk?

Comment: How many permutations of unbalanced do you have? Can you put a limit on how many? (E.g. support 0 to 5 sets of `”` and 0 to 5 sets of `[]`) If so, you can do it with a long and complicated regex. Otherwise you will need to write a custom program to count each and verify.

Comment: @JamesRisner ack or awk; ack is another text finder. There would be no limit other than the length of the string. For instance "[[[]]]" would not be found but "[]]]]]" would, as well as "]]]]]]"

Comment: Good to know on ack. I can’t speak to its feature, but I don’t think you can do `[]` with recursive regex. You should be able to with double quotes.

Comment: Are `][` or `[] ] [ []` balanced? i.e do you need a `]` to be preceded by its corresponding `[` or just the number of `[`s to be the same as the number of `]`s?

Comment: `[^\[\]]*\[(?:[^\[\]]*(?R)?)*+\][^\[\]]*` this seems close https://regex101.com/r/SbNhNO/1

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, any unequal number would be considered unbalanced, so "[]]" and "]][" would be equivalent.

Comment: My question was about `][` or `[] ] [ []` where the number is equal be some `[` don't have a corresponding *following* `]` and some `]` don't have a corresponding *preceding* `[`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, what I should have said was that both `][` and `[] ] [ []` would *not* be considered unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` implementations that support a `-P` for perl-like regexps, you could use their recursive regexp abilities to find lines with matching `[`/`]` pairs and use `-v` to reverse that:

```
grep -Pxv '((\[(?1)\]|[^][])*+)'
```

Requires the `[` to be *followed* by the corresponding `]` i.e `[foo]` is considered balanced but not `]foo[`

Or if the order doesn't matter:

```
grep -Pxv '((\[(?1)\]|\](?1)\[|[^][])*+)'
```

`[foo]` and `]foo[` balanced, `[foo` still not.

That's in effect returning the lines that don't have the same number of `[`s as of `]`s. A simpler way to achieve that would be to just count them.

```
perl -lne '$l = () = /\[/g; $r = () = /\]/g; print if $l != $r'
```

```
awk 'gsub(/\[/, "&") != gsub(/\]/, "&")'
```

With `sed`, you can eliminate pairs in a loop, and print if there are remaining `[`s or `]`s:

```
sed -e 'h;:1' -e 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/g;s/\]\(.*\)\[/\1/g;t1' -e '/[][]/!d;g'
```

Or if the order matters:

```
sed -e 'h;:1' -e 's/\[\([^][]*\)\]/\1/g;t1' -e '/[][]/!d;g'
```